# What is the correct format when setting up Bootstrap containers, rows, columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just started working with Bootstrap and I am trying to wrap my mind around it. I understand how the rows and columns and containers work. I just don't know what the "syntax" is for setting up the divs.

Do I want to do something like this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div>Content Goes In Here</div> 
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Or would it be something like:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row col-xs-12">
    <div>Content Goes In Here</div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Or it might be another way I am not seeing. I just want to make sure the way I am writing the divs for Bootstrap is correct and that I am not using too many DIV's

Do I want all my current code to be css free such ass Width, Height, Padding for the framework to work correctly etc?

Let me know on some direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example is definitely correct:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div>Content Goes In Here</div> 
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

It may seem like a lot of `<div>` tags when you are first starting out, but try to not think of each of them as a `<div>` but rather think of each one as the class they are. For instance, the first one is `container-fluid`, the second one is `row` and the third one is `col-xs-12`.

As a general rule of thumb, the less inline styling the better, yes. Whenever you identify a need to do anything with the width or something that seems like it should be handled by bootstrap, it probably should be and you should look for anything inside of bootstrap that could handle what you want to do.

Here is a more formal tutorial on Bootstrap 3: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

Comment: Ok wow I was doing it half and half, thanks for clearing that up. I'll have to go back and clean up my code. So pretty much any content that you want to resize in the row, should be wrapped in a div that specifies how many columns in that size it should take up in the row?

Comment: from my experience, it is good practice to always include both the `<div class="row">` level and the `col-...` level simply because if you arbitrarily leave it out, you may then run into padding or other formatting issues and not realize why until you remember you didn't add columns here or there (happened to me plenty of times). Another thing to keep in mind and to really get a grasp on are the sizes (i.e. `col-xs`, `col-md` and so on). Bootstrap has a lot of things built in to make websites responsive that end-users are often impressed with